# Как узнать параметры функции и возвращаемый тип из дезассемблированной dll?

Tags: ассемблер

```
; Exported entry   1. CreateDriver

; Attributes: bp-based frame

public CreateDriver
CreateDriver proc near

arg_0= dword ptr  8
arg_4= dword ptr  0Ch

; FUNCTION CHUNK AT CODE:0040BB5A SIZE 00000002 BYTES

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
call    unknown_libname_64 ; BDS 2005-2006 and Delphi6-7 Visual Component Library
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
test    eax, eax
jz      short loc_40BAC6
```

Есть вот такая функция в дизассемблере. Какие у нее параметры, чтобы подключить эту dll и объявить эту функцию? Если можно, аргументы в типах Delphi 7, но сойдут и на с++.

Comment: Вы не можете восстановить типы аргументов надёжно, надо смотреть, как ими пользуется код. `DWORD`, переданный как `arg_0`, может быть числом, а может быть и указателем. Или это вообще неявно переданный `self`, а функция объявлена с одним аргументом.

В вашем случае, кажется, два указателя на что-то размером в DWORD (или меньше). Но не факт.

Comment: Давайте опишу ситуацию. Возможно, поможет. Библиотека - описывает структуры и классы и протокол для управления внешним оборудованием, подключеным через com. По идее данная функция должна провести инициализацию системы. Я не силен в понимании функционирования драйверов. Что туда может быть передано? Номер ком-порта, думаю. Хотя не факт. В самой dll есть класс, описывающий соединение.Сейчас допишу код функwии unknown_libname_64. 

call    unknown_libname_64 ; 
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
test    eax, eax
jz      short loc_40E91E
xor     edx, edx
mov     [eax], edx

Comment: далее loc_40E91E
xor     eax, eax
push    ebp
 push    offset loc_40E971
push    dword ptr fs:[eax]
mov     fs:[eax], esp
mov     eax, ds:off_40F4B0
mov     edx, [ebp+arg_0]
call   @System@@IntfCopy$qqrr45System@_DelphiInterface$t17System@IInterface_x45System@_DelphiInterface$t17System@IInterface_ ; System::__linkproc__ IntfCopy(System::DelphiInterface<System::IInterface> &,System::DelphiInterface<System::IInterface>)
mov     dl, 1
mov     eax, off_4088F8
call    sub_409CB0
mov     edx, eax
test    edx, edx
jz      short loc_40E94E
sub     edx, 0FFFFFFF8h

Comment: @held88, тип аргументов и переменных со 100% точностью можно определить либо **полностью** разобравшись в работе библиотеки, либо если они передаются в функции, тип аргументов которых 100% известен (думаю, это не ваш вариант). По маленькому кусочку кода вряд ли можно что-то определить.

Comment: Да, судя по тому что это Дельфи, первым параметром в функции класса всегда this(self) передаётся. Если это конечно не какая-то служебная и скрытая функция, написанная не в пространстве самого дельфи.